# Google Maps loading files twice

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have really strange problem with Google Maps. Before closing body tag i'm putting this line:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY_IS_HERE&sensor=false"></script>`

And when I'm trying to load the page I get such error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'Load'`

I investigated a little bit, and I know that the problem is connected with loading google maps files twice. I previewed the file and google maps appends two libraries:

`<script src="https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/pl_pl/mapfiles/api-3/15/11/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
and
`<script src="https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/15/11/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

It's loaded dynamicaly. I think that the problem is with two languages: `pl_pl` and `en_us`. But why is it happening? Do You have any ideas how to solve this weird issue ? :D

Comment: It is loaded dynamically? What are you using to create the pages that use Google Maps? Are you using a framework or CMS of some sort

Comment: Nope, it's inside index.html file as normal text. I'm using angular

Comment: Can you give a link to that page?

Comment: http://portal.godetilbud.aftenposten.no/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this script from the source:

```
<script src="https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/15/11/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It will be loaded automatically by https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY_IS_HERE&sensor=false

Comment: i know about that, but the problem is, that this line is missing. I searched all the files and there's no such line in the files

Comment: It must be there, it's definitely coming from serverside. Do you use some caching-technologies on that server?

Comment: Hmm, i did `grep -rl "gstatic" . ` in project dir and it's empty. Only caching technology that we are using is Varnish + phantom for SEO

Comment: OK, i've manage to find the issue. Phantom generates us static files as well, kind of a cache. When Phantom was parsing the website, google maps appended this script to body and it was saved with the link to library. That causes the issue:)